# Android - Enabling MenuItems by code

Tags: android, menuitem

I need to enable a MenuItem when a previous screen (Activity) returns.

I tried this code:

...
((MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.menu_how)).setEnabled(true);
...

but a null pointer exception is launched.

BTW, the menu_how is set to false in xml; and the code is part of onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) call.

Answer (score 6):

I found something at the android dev [site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) that might be helpful (look for the section "Changing menu items at runtime")

It said that the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method fired only when the the menu for the activity is created, and it happens when this activity starts. So if you want to change the menu items after the menu/activity was created, you need to override the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` method instead. search the link for full details.

EDIT:

Just made it and it's working fine. I'm using one `boolean var` per `menuItem` which represents if this item should be enabled or not. This is my code:

```
/*************************************Game Menu**************************************/
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {
        case R.id.gm_new_game:
            //newGame();
            return true;
        case R.id.gm_stand_up:
            //some code when "gm_stand_up" button clicked..
            return true;
        case R.id.gm_forfeit:
            //some code when "gm_forfeit" button clicked..
            return true;
        case R.id.gm_surrender:
            //some code when "gm_surrender" button clicked..
            return true;
        case R.id.gm_exit_table:
            exitTableCommand();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    menu.findItem(R.id.gm_forfeit).setEnabled(forfeitMenuButtonIsEnabled);
    menu.findItem(R.id.gm_surrender).setEnabled(surrenderMenuButtonIsEnabled);
    menu.findItem(R.id.gm_new_game).setEnabled(newGameMenuButtonIsEnabled);
    menu.findItem(R.id.gm_stand_up).setEnabled(standUpMenuButtonIsEnabled);

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try using `menu.findItem(R.id.menu_how)` in onCreateOptionsMenu and save a reference for later use.

This should work fine with `enabled`, however, I've found that setting a menu item to invisible in the XML means you can't show/hide it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>where are you calling this?</strike> (Sorry, didn't read carefully) I think you need to call it after the menu is inflated (usually in OnCreateOptionsMenu). To do this, you can set a variable to true when the other Activity returns, then do `((MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.menu_how)).setEnabled(mMyBooleanField)` in OnCreateOptionsMenu after the call to inflater.inflate.

Edit: To accomplish this in code, it might look something like this:

At the top of the class (along with all the other class members):
`Boolean mEnableMenuItem = false;`

In OnCreateOptionsMenu:
`MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_main, menu);
((MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.menu_how)).setEnabled(mEnableMenuItem );`

In OnActivityResult:
`mEnableMenuItem = true;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but, what I'm trying to do is enabling my MenuItem according to some conditions. This conditions are obtained from another activity so, I've included the ((MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.menu_how)).setEnabled=true in the onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) code. This is causing a null pointer exception.

Comment: That's what the above answer accomplishes. The thing is, I don't think you can set it directly in onActivityResult, you need to indirectly set it using a variable. I'll update my answer to be a little more specific, with code implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to Menu in your activity:

```
private Menu mMenu;
```

Then:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_note, menu);
        mMenu = menu;
        return true;
    }
```

Now, to access menu items anywhere in your activity use similar code to this:

```
mMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_how).setVisible(false);
```

or

```
mMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_how).setEnabled(true);
```